# Is it unethical to file a claim against an attorney who lied?

Tags: united-states, civil-procedure, court, new-jersey

Is it unethical to file a claim with the American Bar Association against the attorney of the opposing party when the attorney lied in court to tip things in his favor (e.g, made a false statement of fact)?

What if the Judge ultimately rejected the attorney's claim?

Is it wrong to bring it to the attention of the judge or do judges frown on such things (since the attorney is representing the other party)?

Comment: It's probably better if you edit your question and remove the "ethical" parts.  This is a law forum not an ethics forum.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it unethical to file a claim against an attorney who lied?

No. It is actually *encouraged* if the claimant can submit proof of attorney's misconduct. The grievance is to be filed in the [claimant's jurisdiction](https://www.njcourts.gov/attorneys/ethics) rather than with the American Bar Association.

An attorney's lies may be severe enough to constitute *fraud on the court* and possibly warrant disbarment. See [*Matter of LaRosee*, 122 N.J. 298, 311 (1991)](https://www.leagle.com/decision/1991420122nj298180).

The real question from a practical standpoint is whether the Disciplinary Review Board and related entities will follow through or be unduly lenient about that attorney's misconduct.

> What if the Judge ultimately rejected the attorney's claim?

That does not reduce the impropriety of the attorney's misconduct. The so-called "zealousness" with which lawyers advance their clients' position does not justify indulging in dishonesty *devised* to result in miscarriage of justice.

> Is it wrong to bring it to the attention of the judge or do judges frown on such things (since the attorney is representing the other party)?

No. Judges generally are not up-to-date about attorneys' misconduct. Putting them on notice might frustrate a crook's further attempts to mislead the court in that and other cases the judge presides.

By not reporting a crook, the public remains exposed to risks from that lawyer's pattern of misconduct.